# Why C++ strings do not need std::forward to call the desired function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

I'm learning `std::forward`. I wrote a short program to test what would happen if we do not call `std::forward` before forwarding the arguments to another function call:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Example {
};

ostream &operator << (ostream &os, const Example &e) { os << "yes!"; return os; }

void test_forward_inner(const Example &e) { cout << "& " << e << endl; }
void test_forward_inner(Example &&e) { cout << "&& " << e << endl; }

void test_forward_inner(const string &e) { cout << "& " << e << endl; }
void test_forward_inner(string &&e) { cout << "&& " << e << endl; }

template <typename T>
void test_forward_wrapper(T &&arg) {
    test_forward_inner(arg);
}

int main()
{
    Example e;
    test_forward_wrapper(e);
    test_forward_wrapper(Example());

    cout << endl;

    string s("hello");
    test_forward_wrapper(s);
    test_forward_wrapper("hello");

    return 0;
}
```

Here I tried to forward a lvalue and an rvalue from `test_forward_wrapper()` to `test_forward_inner()`. Running this program gives the output:

```
& example
& example

& hello
&& hello
```

For `std::string`s, the desired inner function was called, but for my own class only the lvalue version was called. Only if I call `std::forward` before passing the arguments to the inner function can the rvalue version get called.

What makes the difference here? As I know, according to the reference collapsing rules, when the wrapper was called with `Example()`, an rvalue, `T` would be deduced as `Example` and `arg` would have type `Example &&` thus the rvalue version of the inner function should be called.

And, for other situations like the `std::string` case here, the correct version of the inner function was called, then can we remove the `std::forward` here? If not, what (maybe something bad) would happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that `"hello"` is not `std::string`, it's a `const char[6]`. And `test_forward_wrapper()` is a function template, the template argument `T` will be deduced as `char const (&)[6]` for it.

Inside `test_forward_wrapper()`, `test_forward_inner()` is called with `const char[6]`, which need to be converted to `std::string` at first. This is a temporary `std::string`, i.e. a rvalue, preferred to be bound to rvalue reference , that's why `test_forward_inner(string &&)` is called.

Passing an exact `std::string` to `test_forward_wrapper()` will get the same result.

```
test_forward_wrapper(std::string("hello"));
```

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that in

```
test_forward_wrapper("hello");
```

"hello" here isn't a `std::string`. It's a `const char *`.

Change this to a

```
test_forward_wrapper(std::string("hello"));
```

And the result will be the same as the custom class's.

Comment: The important part is that the wrapper is templated (so no coercion occurs in that call), while the inner function is not, only accepting `std::string`, which means the conversion to `string` occurs then (providing a r-value reference to the inner function), no forwarding involved.

Comment: `"hello"` is not a `const char *`, it is a `const char[6]` that can decay into a `const char *`.
.

Comment: ^ (and does not decay in this situation)